# android comparison between arraylist and database?

Tags: android

i am fetching data from server storing it to the database and again storing it to arraylist from database to arraylist and than using in listview.
so suppose if i am using direct database i have to query it numberof times so is there any overhead using direct database.

thnakx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is overhead but the trade off is that you can use much larger datasets with the database cursor without requiring it all in memory. You could always do large fetches and cache locally in an ArrayList within your Cursor. That way you get the benefits of the "infinite scroll" and the ability to do very quick reads within continuous cells.

Comment: hi greg,thankx for reply.but can u suggest me any example by a little bit code.rightnow i am binding data direct from database to listview.

Comment: Well there is not much Code, basically Cursor is an Interface. So it's possible to create a Cursor just for listing whereas you wrap the original Cursor in an implementation which caches queries. This makes the assumption of stableIds. It might not be worth it in the end as CursorAdapters should take care of a lot of this for you, but I was saying if you thought the default behavior was slow there is nothing stopping you from wrapping the original Cursor in a caching cursor.